# Unable to register custom component globally with vue.js

Tags: vue.js

I have made selectbox component and wants to reuse it in other components. Si I want to register that component globally. I have imported that component in main.js but doesnot works.

main.js

```
import Selectbox from "@/modules/Selectbox.vue";
Vue.component("Selectbox", Selectbox);
```

Selectbox.vue

```
<template>
  <div>
    <label>{{ label }}</label>
    <select @change="$emit('input', $event.target.value)">
      <option
        v-for="opt in options"
        :key="opt.value"
        :value="opt.value"
        :selected="value === opt.value"
      >
        {{ errorMessage }}
        {{ opt.label || "No label" }}
      </option>
    </select>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  props: {
    label: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    },
  },
  data() {
    return {
      errorMessage: "",
      option: "lorem",
      options: [
        { label: "lorem", value: "lorem" },
        { label: "ipsum", value: "ipsum" }
      ]
    };
  },
};
</script>
```

Test.vue

```
<template>
<div>
<Selectbox v-model="ward_no"/>
</div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  data() {
   return {
     ward_no: '',
        };
     }
   }
</script>
```

Comment: What error did you get? Please add to your question

Comment: I didn't get any error. @Anatoly

Comment: So what do you mean by 'does not work' then? No errors in console and a component just not shown?

Comment: When I didn't import Selectbox component locally in other components, I got "Uncaught ReferenceError: Selectbox is not defined" @Anatoly

Comment: Can you add an example of Selectbox usage in other component in your post?

Comment: I have included Selectbox component content. @Anatoly

Comment: Update your question with code using Selectbox in another component's template.

Comment: I have updated question. @tao

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing wrong in the way that you are trying to register global component but you are missing `script` tag.

**UPDATE:** After talking to @prabinasht on skype and reviewing her code, I saw that in **multiple** files she forgot to remove locally imported/registered component and at the same time the component was registered globally too, so that was the problem.

Comment: I forgot to write <script> in this post only but there is already in mycode

Comment: @prabinasht in case if you have not fixed yet then let's fix, ping me on skype: syed_haroon

Answer (score -1):

Register the component this way

```
Vue.component('Selectbox', require('@/modules/Selectbox.vue').default)
```